# want to use case statement at the order by

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  RETURN (

     SELECT DISTINCT(Salary) 
     FROM Employee 
     ORDER BY 
     (case
         when N<=0 then Salary  END DESC LIMIT 0,1,
         when N >0 then Salary  END DESC LIMIT N-1,1) 



  );
END
```

I want to use the case statement at the order by 
when N <=0 desc with LIMIT 0,1 and 
N>0 then  Desc with LIMIT N-1,1

Comment: You can only return 1 value in a function - what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: find the Nth highest salary but when N is less then 0 it gives error with minus number then I try to use case when

Comment: Maybe you should return cursor!

Comment: @Nyamkhuu Buyanjargal we are some way from needing a cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants' 'Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables.' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html
Which I take to mean you cannot do arithmetic on on your routine parameters and 
you do get a syntax error (which you should have included in your question). I would just separate the handling of n

```
drop function if exists f;
delimiter $$
CREATE FUNCTION f(N INT) 
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
   if n > 0 then 
        set n = n - 1 ; 
    else
        set n = 0;
    end if;
  RETURN 

     (SELECT DISTINCT(Salary) 
     FROM Employees 
     ORDER BY 
     salary desc limit n,1 
   ) ;
END $$
delimiter ;

select distinct(salary) from employees order by salary desc limit 4;
+--------+
| salary |
+--------+
|  39500 |
|  19500 |
|  16000 |
|  14000 |
+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select f(1), f(-1),f(-10),f(2), f(3),(f4); 

+-------+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+
| f(1)  | f(-1) | f(-10) | f(2)  | f(3)  | f(4)  |
+-------+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+
| 39500 | 39500 |  39500 | 19500 | 16000 | 14000 |
+-------+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: thank you. is there way to do this with case  whenstatement?

Comment: Instead of an if statement?